# Remove the Context Menu in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

TinyMCE has a built-in contextmenu which activates when you right-click in the content editor area.  I need to remove this menu due to the copy/cut/paste in the menu.  It for an application specific reason and less of a technical reason.

[image]

I have attempted to remove the contextmenu plugin as well as attempt to catch the contextmenu event and trap it without luck.

Comment: +1 thanks for screenshot provided

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The easy solution is to remove the contextmenu plugin in your tinymce init:

```
 plugins : "inlinepopups,insertdatetime,fullscreen,contextmenu",
```

becomes

```
 plugins : "inlinepopups,insertdatetime,fullscreen",
```

Comment: I tried this previously; tried it again based on your comment and it worked - browser cache must have been beating on me.  Thanks!

Comment: glad to have been able to help

Comment: I did this with the but it initially didn't work, whenever I right-clicked I get a LINK in the contextual menu, so I went into my plugin and removed LINK from it and then it worked.

Answer (score 15):

In version 5, context menu is built in the core.
This has helped me:

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    contextmenu: false,
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the complete script in **plugins/contextmenu/editor.plugin.js** (It's only 1 line so it's sufficient to put 2 slashes at the start).

It works for me, the contextmenu no longer appears.

Comment: this would work, but it is very ugly because there is a way to configure the contextmenu (which will be no longer possible cause you fiddled with the source code!)

Answer (score 0):

Commenting this line in `/plugins/contextmenu/editor_plugin.js` worked for me:

```
f.addSeparator();f.add({title:"advanced.image_desc",icon:"image",cmd:h.plugins.advimage?"mceAdvImage":"mceImage",ui:true});
```

If for any reason you use the non-minified js, comment this:

```
m.addSeparator();
m.add({title : 'advanced.image_desc', icon : 'image', cmd : ed.plugins.advimage ? 'mceAdvImage' : 'mceImage', ui : true});
```