# Issue with ContextMenu in TinyMCE

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, tinymce

I have put advanced theme in the TinyMCE (3.4.X) configuration and is working fine.

I have disabled Right-Click in DOM so that the user cannot copy/paste anything to the page and it has been done successfully using JQuery.

But, inside this editor it does not seem to be possible at all. I have tried to remove 'contextmenu' from plugin list. But it removed the editor's right-click menu and now its showing browsers normal right click menu and using that a user can do copy/paste activities. So, please let me know whether I can disable both type of context menus.

Thanks :)-

Comment: Since you've already removed 'contextmenu' from plugin list, try the other solutions mentioned for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509082/remove-the-context-menu-in-tinymce).

Comment: I couldn't find any relevant info in the given link. Please confirm