# Disable copy text from tinymce textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tinymce

is there a way to stop copy text from tinymce text area ? i did my try by following code it disable copy from simple text area but i want this restriction on tinymce text area , i am not talking about buttons i am talking about text written in text area

```
<textarea id="mytinymcetextarea" class="noselect">Not copy able</textarea>

tinymce.init({
 selector: "#mytextarea"
});


$('#mytinymcetextarea').bind('copy',function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); return false; 
});
```

i also did try by css

```
.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
    -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
   -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
        user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                              supported by Chrome and Opera */
}
```

if it is not possible is there anyother text editor which allow to disable copy text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to intercept the `copy` event and disable its default behavior:

```
document.addEventListener('copy', function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // default behaviour is to copy selected text
});
```

There's no guarantee this will work on all browsers though.

In addition to this, you could remove the context menu (see: [Remove the Context Menu in TinyMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509082/remove-the-context-menu-in-tinymce)), and you can also remove the "copy" option from the "Edit" menu in TinyMCE (see: http://codeasp.net/blogs/microsoft-net/204/tinymce-how-to-remove-cut-copy-and-paste-items-in-edit-menu).

Comment: Tried this method but it didn't work for me. or may be i'm using it in wrong way. im using google chrome 74.0.3729.131

Comment: I responded directly to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56056893/how-to-disable-copy-paste-in-tinymce/56057291#56057291