# How to Disable Copy/Paste in tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, codeigniter

i'm using tinymce RTF editor on my website. i want to disable copy/paste option in tinymce textarea. i found this method on stackoverflow but it didn't work for me.

[How to Prevent/disable copy and paste in Tinymce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56014001/how-to-prevent-disable-copy-and-paste-in-tinymce)

```
document.addEventListener('paste', function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: See the comment under the answer: "... your second code answer: 'paste_preprocess' is working perfectly. I help me a lot". Use the second solution.

Comment: @TimVN i tried that one too. may I'm not using it in correct way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use `paste_preprocess` if you include the `paste` plugin. If you're using `paste_preprocess`, make sure you're passing it as an option to `tinymce.init()`, and also including the plugin. For example:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    paste_preprocess: function (plugin, args) {
        console.log("Attempted to paste: ", args.content);
        // replace copied text with empty string
        args.content = '';
    },
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
```

See [this **updated** fiddle](https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/xHgaab/15) for an example.

Comment: none of these answers block paste. it just pastes in blank text. For example if the user selects some text, and then attempts to paste in something new, it just replaces the selected text with an empty string, effectively deleting the selection.

Comment: @user323774 I updated the link to the fiddle, as the original link seemed to no longer go to the correct fiddle. However, I still cannot reproduce what you described. If I go to the linked fiddle, type text in the text editor, highlight it, CTRL+C, move cursor to end of the text, and CTRL+V, nothing is added to the text area. You can confirm this by viewing the source as well.

Answer (score 4):

Earlier answers suggesting to replace `args.contents = ''` do not actually prevent a paste operation, they rather alter the contents of the paste to an empty string which still gets pasted.

[TinyMCE Event Doc](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.event/#preventdefault)

This actually prevents the paste completely.

```
paste_preprocess: (plugin, args) => {
    args.stopImmediatePropagation();
    args.stopPropagation();
    args.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As previously answered, you can use `paste_preprocess`. However, you'll need to add `paste` to `plugins`.

Example:

```
tinymce.init({
  ...,
  plugins: [
    "paste"
  ],
  paste_preprocess: function (plugin, args) {
    console.log(args.content);
    args.content = '';
  }
});
```

Comment: You can open the javascript console by hitting ```CTRL``` + ```SHIFT``` + ```J```. See the error. If you directly copied this piece of code, it won't work. I put ```...``` in place of your other configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept paste in the `tinymce.init`

```
paste_preprocess: function(plugin, args) {
    console.log(args.content);
    args.content = '';
  }
```

Comment: i tried this method but it doesn't work for me. im using this  like this 

tinymce.init({
  paste_preprocess: function(plugin, args) {
    console.log(args.content);
    args.content = '';
  }
});